# Custom jQuery UI that doesn't have dialog and modal, needs a background overlay under the dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I'm clicking on the second image with the pink background, a dialog appears. I need a background overlay under it which doesn't appear when I'm using modal: true because I have a customized library in my project. How can I add this background under the dialog box without using `modal: true`?

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
       //modal: true,
       autoOpen: false,  
    });
    $(".images").find("a").eq(1).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.href = $(this).prop("href");
        }, 5000);
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open");
    });
});
```

```css
#dialog {
        display: none;
    }
    
img {
        width: 300px;
        height: 250px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
<!-- These scripts include the full jQuery UI -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src=""></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <div class="images">
        <a href="https://www.site1.com">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/413727/pexels-photo-413727.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Image 1">
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.site2.com">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1036623/pexels-photo-1036623.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog" title="Lorem ipsum">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod amet, et minus commodi repellendus hic? Ut eos blanditiis quis provident.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `dialog` event within the click function for `dialog` to be **initialized** at the same when you the `click` event occurs.

To change the `background pink` you can either use CSS with `!important` rule OR you can use `addClass` to the your `dialogue` when it opens.

**Edit:** Since you do not want the `modal: true` option for your `library` reasons. You can use `addClass` and `removeClass` of jQuery to add a custom modal to you `body` and `remove` the `class` on `dialogue` close.

**Live Working Demo:** (Both images showing dialogue with `pink` background modal)

```js
$(function() {

  $(".images").find("a").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //dialog box
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      open: function(e) {
        $('body').addClass('modal');
      },
      close: function(e) {
        $('body').removeClass('modal');
      }
    }).dialog("open");

    //Href
    setTimeout(() => {
      // window.location.href = $(this).prop("href");
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.modal {
  background-color: pink;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#dialog {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- These scripts include the full jQuery UI -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src=""></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="images">
  <a href="https://www.site1.com">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/413727/pexels-photo-413727.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Image 1">
  </a>
  <br>
  <a href="https://www.site2.com">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1036623/pexels-photo-1036623.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Lorem ipsum">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod amet, et minus commodi repellendus hic? Ut eos blanditiis quis provident.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is not what I am looking for because maybe I did not explained very well. If I'm clicking on the second image with the pink background, a dialog appears. I need a background overlay, like in modals, under it which doesn't appear when I'm using `modal: true` because I have a customized library in my project

Comment: Think of the dialog box like a modal window. You have the box with text and under it you need to hide the whole page under darker background

Comment: @JustMe setitng `modal: true` and using doing `custom CSS` to make it look like a modal will have the results you want here. Like a normal window modal. Its very unusual what you are trying to do the hard way which can be achieved easily - Can you show me an example or perhaps a drawing ?

Comment: My customized library which I can't include it here, seems to be missing some components so I can't use simply `modal: true` as I want. Can you please show me how can I add a background overlay to this box that pops up without using modal: true ? Thanks!

Comment: @JustMe Using custom CSS yes it could be possilbe without modal: true - Thanks for clarifying the libary part  - I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks! I'm eager to  see how to do it

Comment: @JustMe See my edited  answer all working without `modal: true`.

Comment: Thank you! I applied your solution here https://jsfiddle.net/ew6guq43/2/ and now I'm wondering why the dialog box gets darker too. Any tips regarding this?

Comment: @JustMe Yeah sure. Thats because you are using full dark barkground and dialogue color light white faded by the library. You can either set the color yourself to like full white for everything. background as black will have affect it very darker web pages.